# Django "Client class" integration into VS Code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I have had several issues integrating Django testing into VSCode. Finally I succeeded to run most kinds of tests (the trick, it seems, is to run django.setup() before anything else happens, including importing Django modules), but now I am having a problem with Django's client class. I do a simple client.get() and I get a 400 (Bad Request) error from within VSCode. But if I run "python manage.py test" from the CLI the test works! I am completely at a loss as to what is happening...

Here is my code. It couldn't be simpler.

```
import logging

import django

django.setup()

from django.test import Client, TestCase  # noqa: E402
from django.db import DatabaseError   # noqa: E402

logger = logging.getLogger('XXXX.debugger')


class WorkflowAPIClient(TestCase):
   
    def test_createWorkflow(self):
   
        client = Client()

        resp = client.get('/workflow/')
        
        logger.debug(f'After request: {resp.status_code} - {resp.content}')
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

When I run this from the CLI as "python manage.py test" it runs OK (assertEqual succeeds).
When I try to run this from the test module of VSCode, it gives a status_code of 400 and
thus assertEqual fails.

I am using unittest for the VSCode test configuration and it discovers the test files without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

400 error is usually caused by unable to access the domain name. You could debug to check the problem or check whether it is ALLOWED_HOSTS error.

Comment: Thanks. I am running the server locally and it is available via "normal" Django (i.e. python manage.py runserver or python manage.py test). It seems this is related to VS Code somehow.

Comment: Then you can check whether the configuration "terminal.integrated.env.windows" in the setting.json file is correct. And provide the contents in the output when an error is reported, this can help me a lot.

Comment: Hello, Ming, sorry for the delay, I was on holiday. I have checked the following settings.json files and that variable is never set:



.vscode/extensions/pachwenko.django-test-runner-3.0.4/.vscode/settings.json
.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044/pythonFiles/.vscode/settings.json
.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.10.1365161279/pythonFiles/.vscode/settings.json
.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.10.1365161279/resources/report_issue_user_settings.json


No other setting.json file under .vscode

Comment: @Luis Fernando Areán Have you debugged on vscode?